# Z-Substitution of Integrals

Tags: integration

I'm busy studying for my Calculus exam and came across something that I'm not too sure about. The question asks to use z-substitution to determine an integral. The actual question is:

```
Use z=tan(x/2) to determine the integral:
Integral from 0 to pi/3 of dx/(3+2cosx)
```

Is Z-Substitution the same as normal substitution but they give you what to use? Or is there another method?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a standard substitution for evaluating integrals of rational functions of trigonometric functions. A more common name is the [Weierstrass substitution.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_substitution)

You will find full details in the Wikipedia article linked to above.